# How to specify the number of X ticks and their labels in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some data using the `pyplot.plot()` function of **Matplotlib**.

The X values for the data are integers, but these numbers do not mean anything.
For example:

```
x_vals = [2, 34, 456, 999, 10000]
```

But, matplotlib thinks these are actual X values. It scales the X axis and shows ticks like this on the plot:

```
|
|
|
|
+---+----+----+----+----+
0   2000 4000 6000 8000 10000
```

What I want is for matplotlib to blindly plot using X axis like this:

```
|
|
|
|
+---+----+----+----+
2   34   456  999  10000
```

That is, I want the number of ticks to be equal to the number of X values I passed in. I also want the values to be blindly interpreted, possibly as strings.

How can this be done in Matplotlib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to plot a `range` instead of the actual x-values along the x-axis, and then manually change the labels to the desired values.

In other words:

```
plt.plot(range(len(y_values)), y_values)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_ticklabels(x_values)
```

where, in this case, `x_values = [2, 34, 10000]`.

Comment: Thanks. In addition, I found that it is also necessary to set the number of X ticks. I have made the modification and accepted your answer :)

Comment: Rolled back to my original answer. See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/223330) for more information as to why.